# Does Playwright have equivalent functionality to "--findRelatedTests" in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, playwright, pre-commit-hook, playwright-test, lint-staged

I will be running Playwright VR Tests with a pre-commit hook. My test files are co-located with each compoinent. Instead of running all tests each time, I am looking for a feature (or other solution) that will only run the tests in directories that have changed/staged files. This would be similar to the `findRelatedTests` flag with Jest.

I have looked through Playwright's docs and issue queue to see if this has been addressed already.